# file-type: extract mime type

Tags: typescript, mime-types, file-type

I am using the `file-type` package (https://www.npmjs.com/package/file-type) to determine the mime type of a file from a buffer. The function returns a promise, and I would like to extract only the mime like this `application/dicom`.

```
const mimeType = await FileType.fromBuffer(buffer);
console.log(mimeType); // { ext: 'dcm', mime: 'application/dicom' }
```

Is something like this possible?

```
const { ext, mime } = await FileType.fromBuffer(buffer);
console.log(ext);
console.log(mime);
```

Comment: yes you can do it just like that

Comment: @dave I got this error `Property 'mime' does not exist on type 'FileTypeResult | undefined'.ts(2339)`

Comment: ah then you can either do `const { ext, mime } = await FileType.fromBuffer(buffer) || { mine: 'unknown', ext: 'unknown' }` or probably even just `const { ext, mime } = await FileType.fromBuffer(buffer) as FileTypeResult`

Comment: Thank you! Worked perfectly:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either do

```
const { ext, mime } = await FileType.fromBuffer(buffer) || { mine: 'unknown', ext: 'unknown' }
```

or probably even just

```
const { ext, mime } = await FileType.fromBuffer(buffer) as FileTypeResult
```